# All System.Net.HttpWebRequest in C# requests are redirected to localhost:54653

Tags: c#, localhost, httpwebrequest, http-redirect

I have a C# service that makes calls to external JSON services and since about two days ago all System.Net.HttpWebRequest's get's redirected to a locahost:54653 address. The port is not active but I cannot seem to find the reason why this is happening. I've tried many different methods and each produces the same results. It seems I have something within the .net framework redirecting traffic for each call.

```
InnerException = {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:54653"}
```

Any ideas on why all C# traffic get redirected?

Comment: If you do not specify otherwise, `HttpWebRequest` uses your system http proxy settings (the same ones that IE uses).  Perhaps you have an http proxy setting pointing to localhost:54653?

Comment: That is what I thought but all other web browsing works without any issues. It's C# code that has this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for providing all this feedback, but it might be useful for the next person.

the windows service runs as "local system" account and the proxy setting for that account is retrieved from the following registry key:

```
HKEY_USERS\.default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections
```

It turned out that this was caused by a virus...

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the app.config file resolves the problem:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="False" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```